# Setting the height of the axis lines in jqplot

Tags: jqplot

I am using jqplot charting with the axis interval as 2, but as seen in the picture, the axis label marker is marked outside of the div of the chart container.

[image]

Is there a way we can fix this issue. kindly advise

Comment: can you please share your code or prepare a jsfiddle. it makes it easy for people to understand what you are trying to do. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand completely what you want, but try yaxis :

```
   title: "JPlot Example",
    axes:{yaxis:{min:-10, max:20}},
    series:[{color:'#5FAB78', markerOptions: { style:"circle" }}],
```